# What is the correct way to lazy load modules in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I had lazy loading of modules in my angular app in angular 4 which worked perfectly . The lazy routing was inside `app.module.ts` like this :

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: 'recDet', component: RecDetComponent },
          { path: 'SlaveComponent/:pfScreen', loadChildren: './ally/slave/slave.module#SlaveModule' }
  ])
```

Now I have migrated the app to angular 7, which gives me this error during compilation :

> `ERROR in ./src/app/slaveModule/slave-module/slave.module.ts Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js): Error: C:\Users\TDK\src\app\slaveModule\slave-module\slave.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.`

I have also seen that lazy loading of modules can also be done by using the attribute : `lazyModules` in `angular.json`.

What is the correct way to have lazy loading implemented in angular 7 via  `app.module.ts` or via `angular.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test', loadChildren: () => import('./test/test.module').then((m) => m.TestModule) },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then I import my app-routing.module in the app.module.

Update:
from the v7 doc: https://v7.angular.io/guide/router#milestone-6-asynchronous-routing
you should declare it like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestModule' },
];
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin . Is that what you are using in Angular 7 for your app ? @Quentin Fonck

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yeah that's what we are using since the beginning of our project (angular version 6). We are now in version 10 but the code didn't change from there. Give it a go and let me know.

Comment: Sure Quentin. Let me try this one out and see what happens

Comment: I made an edit from the V7 doc. May be it will suit your needs better.